# Alamofire GET request from Server API

Tags: swift, sockets, sdk, alamofire

I'm just getting acquainted with Alamofire (using Alamofire 4 with Xcode 8, Swift3, iOS 10)

I'm attempting to use HTTP protocol methods on a on a server API given the an ip address of XXX.XXX.X.XX

To take a photo with the SDK I'm using, I must use a GET request. The documentation states it like this:

Take the photo
GET takepic/true
Trigger the camera to take a photo
Return http status code 200 means OK, 500 means failed

The thing is, I'm not sure how to successfully get the data from the server, and also do not know how to use this "takepic/true" property I'm given.

I attempted the issue like so:

```
 Alamofire.request("http://myIPAddress", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let status = response.response?.statusCode
        {
            switch(status)
            {
            case 200:
                print("example success")
            case 500:
                print("The response failed")
            default:
                print("error with response status: \(status)")
            }
        }

        if let result = response.result.value
        {
            print(result)
        }

    }
```

After running the app, I get a bunch of text in my console. Here's some of the stuff it says:

```
nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
```

nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.9.67:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect

I searched for my print statement which meant success, but could not find it. I could not find any of my other print statements either.

EDIT: The text in my console window comes from me installing SISocket to my project via Cocoapods.

My "result" returns this:

```
expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8).
```

The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.